# firefox drag and drop img as SVG

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I'm trying to implement drag and drop img - svg on canvas.
But there seems to be a problem when using Firefox.

Everything works perfect on Chrome and IE,
plus on Fireforx it works when the img is .jpg or .png, but it ignores svg...

heres the code: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/v8g7wgwx/

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
    this.classList.add('img_dragging');
}
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?